# group by multiple columns without getting result

Tags: oracle, jpa, jpql

I am executing the query on toad editor  and I am getting the appropriate result. However, when I run it on my eclipse, the query is executed normally without errors but my result list is showing zero records.Which changes should I make ?

```
Query query =entityManager.createQuery(" select s.name,c.event_name, count(*) from "
                    + " HistoryEntity c ,ServiceEntity s  "
                    + " where "
                    +" s.code=c.code"
                    + " AND "
                    + "c.entry_date  BETWEEN :dateDeb  AND :dateFin "
                    + " AND "
                    + " c.state='FINAL'"
                    + " AND "
                    + " c.idc= :idc"
                    + " group by s.name, c.event_name order by s.name, c.event_name"
                    );
        query.setParameter("dateDeb", dateDeb);
        query.setParameter("dateFin", dateFin);
        query.setParameter("idc", idc); 

        resultList = query.getResultList();

        LOG.info("Query done "+ resultList.size());
```

Comment: please post code how you are executing query

Comment: What datatype is `IDC` in your table?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar it's a String